# Html- deleting a row from a database

Tags: javascript, html, database, jsp, checkbox

I'm trying to delete a row from my MS access database using checkboxes in my HTML/JSP file. The file currently outputs the database to the UI, after the checkbox is ticked and delete is pressed, a prompt pops ups. But I still CAN'T delete the row from my database. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

see code below:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>DELETE Operation</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteEmployee(rowid){
input_box = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?");
if (input_box == true) {
    // Output when OK is clicked
        $('#' + rowid).remove();
        alert('Record Deleted');
} else {
    // Output when Cancel is clicked
    return false;
}
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<sql:setDataSource
    var = "bookdB"
    scope = "session"
    driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
    url = "jdbc:odbc:bookdB"
/>

<sql:query dataSource="${bookdB}" var="result">
   SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Emp ID</th>
   <th>First Name</th>
   <th>Last Name</th>
   <th>Age</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<form method="post" action="reserve.jsp">
<tr id="${row.id}">
    <td><input type = "checkbox" value="${row.id}" name="empIds"></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
</c:forEach>
<input type="button" value="delete" onclick="deleteEmployee('${row.id}');" />
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good to see you again, but this is the code i really expected from your side.

Comment: Hi again, Thought a fresh post would be the best way to help solve this.

Comment: I just removed my  previous comment  and posted as answer for better understanding. Also i am just leaving for the day. Try that code and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Great, This would help you to resolve the issue. Check out the script below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteEmployee(){

var empIds = [];
$("input[name='empIds']").each(function() {
empIds.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(empIds);

input_box = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?");
if (input_box == true) {
// Output when OK is clicked

 // Uncomment this code for check your UI part.
 //  $("input[name='empIds']").each(function() {
 //       $('#' + $(this).val()).remove();
 //   });
 //   alert('Record(s) Deleted');

$.ajax({
    url : 'reserve.jsp?empIds='+empIds,
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    success : function() {
        $("input[name='empIds']").each(function() {
            $('#' + $(this).val()).remove();
        });
        alert('Record(s) Deleted');
    }
});

    $('#' + rowid).remove();
    alert('Record Deleted');
} else {
// Output when Cancel is clicked
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

And in your html part,

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>Emp ID</th>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<form method="post" action="reserve.jsp">
<tr id="${row.id}">
<td><input type = "checkbox" value="${row.id}" name="empIds"></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
</c:forEach>
<input type="button" value="delete" onclick="deleteEmployee();" />
</table>
```

Forget about the ajax initially, make sure that you will get correct row id on button 
click by using `console.log(empIds)` or `alert(empIds);` inside your function. Hope you will definitely get this time if your db part is correct.

Comment: Hi Vinoth, Thanks again for the update. Sorry, but its not working. when I use the above code, the delete confirmation prompt doesn't pop-up.

Comment: If I put in the code below it would delete one record from my database, but the problem is i have to set that Id in the code, so in this case its 103 .                                                                         <sql:setDataSource
  var = "bookdB"
  scope = "session"
  driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
  url = "jdbc:odbc:bookdB"
    />
    <c:set var="empId" value="103"/>
  
     <sql:update dataSource="${bookdB}" var="count">
       DELETE FROM Employees WHERE Id = ?
       <sql:param value="${empId}" />
    </sql:update>'

Comment: Instead of passing your request into jsp, pass it into some servlet class. There you can receive the id and do your delete. JSP is not a recommended place to doing your DB manipulations.

Comment: I made a new function, and I can delete the row with the checkbox from the UI now, but I still can't remove it from the Access database. This is still in the JSP file. I appreciate the recommendation, but the rest of my website is JSP. Don't wanna have to change it all.

Comment: Do me a favor, can u show me your new function and code that you used for delete record? You can edit your question and update it.